# Extract from determined filters the last and the previous date in posgresql in a wider way

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    the_debt_pay_id varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid timestamp NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0104', '2020-08-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0103', '2020-07-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0102', '2020-06-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0101', '2020-05-02', '2020-04-28 02:28:41'),
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0203', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-01 06:29:53'),
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0202', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-02 07:30:59'),   
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0201', '2020-02-02', '2020-01-31 06:58:18')
```

And I want to query this table in order to get a determined `the_debt_pay_id` and the previous one `the_debt_due` date, so this is the expected output:

```
the_debt_id    the_debt_pay_id    the_debt_due     the_debt_due_previous
LMUS01         LMUS0103           2020-07-02       2020-06-02
LMUS02         LMUS0202           2020-03-02       2020-02-02
```

I guess that function lag could help, but I can't figure it out.

```
SELECT the_debt_id, the_debt_pay_id, the_debt_due 
LAG(the_debt_due,1) OVER (PARTITION BY the_debt_id ORDER BY the_debt_due) the_debt_due_previous 
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_debt_pay_id IN ('LMUS0103','LMUS0202')
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try below. Where i mention where clause outside of partition query:

```
select * from (SELECT the_debt_id, the_debt_pay_id, the_debt_due as the_debt_due,
LAG(the_debt_due,1) OVER (PARTITION BY the_debt_id ORDER BY the_debt_due asc ) the_debt_due_previous  
FROM my_table) as A
WHERE the_debt_pay_id IN ('LMUS0103','LMUS0202')
```

Comment: Hello @jainvikram444, thanks for the answer, works fine. Just a question, is it necessary to explicitly indicate `ASC` in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: "ASC" order not necessary if you want an ASC order.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use the filter(WHERE) clause in initial query, apply it later

```
SELECT the_debt_id, the_debt_pay_id, the_debt_due ,
LEAD(the_debt_due) 
OVER (PARTITION BY the_debt_id ORDER BY the_debt_due) the_debt_due_previous 
FROM my_table;
```

Final query should be:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c1c8/9)

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT the_debt_id, the_debt_pay_id, the_debt_due ,
LAG(the_debt_due) 
OVER (PARTITION BY the_debt_id ORDER BY the_debt_due) the_debt_due_previous 
FROM my_table ) X
WHERE the_debt_pay_id IN ('LMUS0103','LMUS0202');
```

Reason for the above behaviour is that window  function/over clause is applied on the result set obtained after the where clause.

So in your case if you are filtering the result and then there will be only two records in the result set and for 1 per each partition and hence lag/lead will give you null values.

Comment: Hello @Atif, I ran your query in this fiddle [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2ceaff2199adec0d947ab14f2c1a306f] but it return me the following `the_debt_due`, not the previous which I needed

Comment: I have updated my answer, need to replace LEAD with LAG. If its answers your question then upvote it or marked as answered.